# How to register default "EditorClass" of "TAlign" to a "SubRange" of "TAlign" in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, types

I have a "TSimpleAlign" type which is a subrange of "TAlign".

```
type
  TSimpleAlign = TAlign.alTop..TAlign.alRight;
```

I would like to register the editor of this type in the "Object Inspector" as a "TAlign", but I do not know which "EditorClass" of this type is. The purpose is to display the default "Talign" icons.
[image]

I would like to complete the registration below:

```
RegisterPropertyEditor (TypeInfo (TSimpleAlign), TSimpleAction, 'Align', ????);
```

Googling out there I found [this](https://prog.hu/tudastar/19202/property-editor-ertekeinek-modositasa) tip that came close, but, does not work for my purpose:

```
type
  TSimpleAlignProperty = class (TEnumProperty)
  public
    procedure GetValues ​​(Proc: TGetStrProc); override;
    procedure SetValue (const Value: string); override;
  end;
....

procedure Register;
begin
...
  RegisterPropertyEditor (TypeInfo (TAlign), nil, 'Align', TSimpleAlignProperty);
end;

...

{TSimpleAlignProperty}

procedure TSimpleAlignProperty.GetValues ​​(Proc: TGetStrProc);
begin
  Proc ('alTop');
  Proc ('alBottom');
  Proc ('alLeft');
  Proc ('alRight');
end;

procedure TSimpleAlignProperty.SetValue (const Value: string);
begin
  if (Value <> 'alNone') and (Value <> 'alClient') and (Value <> 'alCustom') then
    inherited;
end;
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Why are you using a sub-range of `TAlign` instead of just defining your own enum? `type TSimpleAlign = (salTop, salBottom, salLeft, salRight);` Your registration needs to use `TypeInfo(TSimpleAlign)`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Because it is simpler for my implementation. I have some components that will receive this TSimpleAlign and with the subrange I can set their Align directly without having to convert the type. Also because the enum type will not be published if I make another enum with explicitly defined values.

Comment: There is nothing special about the property editor for `TAlign`, it is just the standard enum editor. If you are going to create your own editor, you have to register it correctly. Registering it using `TypeInfo(TAlign)` only works if you use `TAlign` as your property type (just have its setter method ignore unwanted values). Otherwise you must define a new type (an actual enum is best, not a subrange, then you don't need a custom editor registration at all). Besides, translating values from one enum to another is very trivial. Just write a helper function for it

Comment: "*Also because the enum type will not be published if I make another enum with explicitly defined values*" - what is that even supposed to mean??

Comment: @RemyLebeau See the image above. See that Delphi XE5 has a custom editor class to TAlign

Comment: defining a sub-range requires creating a new type with its own RTTI. Even if you could access the default `TAlign` property editor class (which you can't, as its source code is not provided), you can't use it for a custom property that is not actually using `TAlign` as-is. Your only option in this situation is to write your own property editor from scratch and implement your own icons for it.